# What determines priority in protocol conformance?

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

just curious about something.

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "page"
}
```

If I were to place String after the CodingKey protocol I would get an error saying I need to place String before.. well what determines the priority and why does that even matter? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocol conformance order does not matter. In your case you are getting an error when you place `String` after `CodingKey` is because `String` is not a protocol. It is a struct. Look at the error message what you get in Xcode:

> Raw type 'String' must appear first in the enum inheritance clause

By placing `String` after the enum declaration will define its raw value.

To prove the point let's define two protocols:

```
protocol Protocol1 { }

protocol Protocol2 { }
```

And try to change the order they conform to your `CodingKeys` enum. This would be valid:

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, Protocol1, Protocol2 {
    case id = "page"
}
```

And this is valid too:

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, Protocol2, Protocol1 {
    case id = "page"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but now that knowledge makes me wonder about something else... structs can serve as a superclass?? I thought we could only subclass.. well, other classes..

Comment: Yes, that's correct. From structs you can't inherit. But it's not inheritance, as with normal classes. It indicates the raw type of the enum.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a language requirement that for a declaration of *Enumerations with Cases of a Raw-Value Type* the raw-value type must come before any adopted protocol.

See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID364

Comment: So would this be the only instance a `struct` is in the position of a subclass here.

Comment: A `struct` cannot have subclasses. An enum has its own declaration rules.